# A group of order $120$ has a subgroup of index $3$ or $5$ (or both)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

What I have tried that number of $2$-sylow subgroup can be $1,3,5$ or $15$.I have solved the problem when the number of $2$-sylow subgroup is $1,3,5$. But I am not able to solve it for $15$.

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there are $15$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, and let $S$ be one of them. Note that $N_G(S)=S$. If $S$ is not maximal, then it is contained in a subgroup of index $3$ or $5$, so assume it is maximal.

Consider the permutation representation of $G$ by left multiplication on the left cosets of $S$. Then $S$ is a point stabilizer. If $S$ fixes more than one point in this representation, then the normalizer $N_G(S)$ permutes the fixed points and strictly contains $S$, contradicting $N_G(S)=S$.

So $S$ fixes a unique point. Since its orbits have length a power of $2$ and their lengths add up to $15$, there must be an orbit of length $2$. The point stabilizer $T$ of that orbit has index $2$ in $S$ and (since it stabilizes more than one point) it lies in more than one Sylow subgroup. So $N_G(T)$ properly contains $S$. If $N_G(T) = G$ then $T \lhd G$ and $|G/T| = 30$. Now all groups of order $30$ have subgroups of index $3$ and $5$ (exercise), and hence so does $G$. Otherwise $S < N_G(T) < G$, contradicting maximality of $S$.

Comment: Thank you @Derek Holt for your help...First part of the proof is clear to me..but for the second part of the proof I have to think to understand properly...

Comment: There might be an easier proof but this is the only one I could think of. Let me know if you want any more details.

Comment: you said that "there must be an orbit of length 2"...why it can be all 1 length orbit?Could you please explain me little elaborately third paragraph of your answer,if possible.I thank you again for your help.

Comment: The early assumption/deduction of maximality is unnecessary. By sylow $N_G(S)$ has index 15, whence must be $S$.

Comment: @SahaR We showed in the preceding step that $S$ has only one fixed point i.e. it has a single orbit of length 1. The lengths of the orbits are powers of 2 and must add up to 15, so there must be at least one orbit of length 2. (For example, the lengths could be $1,2,4,8$, or $1,2,2,2,4,4$.)

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes, what you say simplifies the argument in the second paragraph, which I have now edited. But we still need the maximality of $S$ in the third paragraph.

Comment: OK..Now I understood that doubt..Thank you @DerekHolt

Comment: There is this theorem 1.16 in Isaacs: Suppose that $G$ is a finite group such that $n_p(G)>1$, and choose distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups $S$ and $T$ of $G$ such that the order $|S\cap T|$ is as large as possible. Then $n_p(G)\equiv 1 \;\;mod \;|S:S\cap T|$.

Comment: If $n_2(G)=15$ then $|S\cap T | = 4.$ Then, $D=S\cap T \triangleright S, T$. We then consider the mapping, $G \rightarrow G/D $. Note that $|G:D|=2\cdot 3\cdot 
 5 = 30$